# What's the meaning of 'flying black flags' in the sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> After nearly 3,000 coalition airstrikes, the days of freely moving
>   around in large formations, **flying black flags** and taking territory
>   may be over for the group.

[[Source: CNN.Com](http://edition.cnn.com/2015/03/09/world/iraq-tikrit-battle/')]

What's the meaning of 'flying black flags' in the sentence above?

I searched its meaning in the dictionary
(http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fly)

but I couldn't find the answer.

Comment: You didn't find it in the dictionary because it's not an idiom. It's meant to be interpreted literally, and simply means "flying [the group's] black flags."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase "flying black flags" refers to the black flags flown by jihadists.  It's saying that after such a military campaign, those militants who had free reign to move around before are no longer able to move around freely, particularly not in groups or under their raised black banners.

> Many are familiar with what some call “the **black flags** of jihad” flown
>   by Islamic extremists from Jabhat al-Nusra to Al Qaeda.  The flags
>   vary in appearance, but most share a similar theme: they typically
>   have white writing on a black flag, and depict the shehada, or
>   profession of faith that there is no god but god, and Muhammad is his
>   messenger.

[[Blaze.com](http://www.theblaze.com/stories/2013/09/25/do-you-know-the-history-behind-the-black-flags-of-jihad-theblazes-buck-sexton-breaks-it-down/)]

> ISIS Militants Are Now Flying Their **Black Flags** Over Iraq’s Largest
>   Oil Refinery.

[[RYOT Headline](http://www.ryot.org/isis-militants-now-flying-black-flags-iraqs-largest-oil-refinery/725725)]

Comment: I've no idea why some anonymous person down-voted you on this. Anyway +1 for a good answer.

Comment: Hi, Benjamin, I edited your post to copy and paste essential parts of the links. Please take a look.